# Google cloud storage - Download object from Android app

Tags: android, google-cloud-storage, progress-bar

I am writing a simple android library which downloads files stored in 
GCS. The code below works fine

```
Storage storage = StorageOptions.newBuilder()
                        .setProjectId(PROJECT_ID)
                        .setCredentials(ServiceAccountCredentials.fromStream(getAssets().open(JSON_CREDENTIAL)))
                        .build()
                        .getService();
            Blob blob = storage.get(BlobId.of(BUCKET_NAME, BLOB_NAME));
            ReadChannel readChannel = blob.reader();
            FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(filePath);
            fileOutputStream.getChannel().transferFrom(readChannel, 0, Long.MAX_VALUE);
            fileOutputStream.close();
```

1) But the problem is I need to give the progress of the download and I couldn't find any callbacks for the above methods?

2) Also, is this the best way to download files from GCS to android app. I cannot use firebase because, this code is present in a library and used by many client apps and firebase requires all the client apps to be linked to the firebase account, which I don't want to do.

Comment: If you want progress, consider just reading and writing streams rather than using `transferFrom`, which copies the data internally between channels in one shot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [@Doug](https://stackoverflow.com/users/807126/doug-stevenson) said to be able to get a progress bar is better with streams.

Your code will be something like this:

```
        Storage storage = StorageOptions.newBuilder()
                                .setProjectId(PROJECT_ID)
                                .setCredentials(ServiceAccountCredentials.fromStream(getAssets().open(JSON_CREDENTIAL)))
                                .build()
                                .getService();
        int BUFFER_SIZE = 64 * 1024;
        Blob blob = storage.get(BlobId.of(BUCKET_NAME, BLOB_NAME));
        ReadChannel readChannel = blob.reader();
        byte[] content = null;
        if (blob != null) {
            reader = blob.reader();
            ByteBuffer bytes = ByteBuffer.allocate(BUFFER_SIZE);

            while (reader.read(bytes) > 0) {
                bytes.flip();
                content = ArrayUtils.addAll(content,bytes.array());
                bytes.clear();
                //Here you can add the progress bar logic
            }
        }

        FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(filePath);
        fileOutputStream.write(content);
        fileOutputStream.close();
```